# Soup has a floral taste

Tags: soup

Why does my home made Split pea & ham hock soup have a floral taste--I used fresh onions, carrots, Celery, Bay leaf, Vegetable Broth and pepper

Comment: Adding more details on the recipe (proportions & method) would be helpful. Ex) Bay leaf can be very strongly flavored if not cooked long enough... But without more detail, answers will be guessing. That might help you today, but less helpful to the next person who reads this question.

Comment: am I the only one who would love to try a split pea soup with a floral taste?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know what you're tasting, but most likely the bay leaf.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to take that taste away

Comment: You can only 'remove' a flavour by dilution. Best would be to check if that's what you're actually tasting. Soak a bay leaf in a cup of boiling water for 15 mins, sniff & taste, for confirmation.

Comment: Tetsujin's suggestion is good for determining if that's what you're tasting. If you want less of that taste just break the bay laurel in half (or less) and only use part of it. It's a pretty strong flavor.

Comment: @Tetsujin  hi!  there are other mechanisms besides dilution.  random examples:  horseradish and ginger flavors can be cooked out over time.  sweetness is the dominant basic flavor and can hide other flavors without dilution.  fat can be physically removed or hidden by emulsion, salt, and black pepper.  capsicum heat can be blocked with fat.

Answer (score 1):

**Camouflage with tomatoes.**

Re the floral - could be the bay, or maybe store bought vegetable stock.  If you have some that you did not use you could taste it and see.  Sometimes store-bought stock has some weird off flavors.

Re disguising it - I think tomato is a good flavor with ham / split pea or at least not a bad flavor.  Try adding some tomato paste or tomato sauce.

If you still get the floral, try adding some chili powder.  Chili powder is the great equalizer.  When I make "clean out the fridge beans" it is the chili powder that makes all the ingredients get along.  If chili is not to your taste curry powder would work.  Maybe curry would be better...

A purist might argue that it is no longer ham hock and split pea soup with chili powder and tomatoes.  Bring the soup back to the purist when she is hungry and see what then.